# Extract only rows from a specific dataset in R?

Tags: r, sorting, row

I have a table which looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    "seqid" = c("12", "12", "13", "12", "12", "15"),
    "source" = c("star", "star", "star", "star", "star", "star"), 
    "type" = c("CDS", "CDS", "CDS", "intron", "CDS", "intron"),
    "start" = c("15", "21", "23", "35", "45", "60"), 
    "end" = c("70", "80", "86", "45", "67", "88"),
     "attributes" = c("ENSOCUT00000011013", "ENSOCUT00000064484", 
      "ENSOCUT00000013302", 
     "ENSOCUT00000010968", "ENSOCUT00000010968", "ENSOCUT00000060283"),
    stringsAsFactors = F,check.names=FALSE)
```

| seqid | source | Type | start | end | attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | star | CDS | 15 | 70 | ENSOCUT00000011013 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 21 | 80 | ENSOCUT00000064484 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 23 | 86 | ENSOCUT00000013302 |
| 12 | star | intron | 35 | 45 | ENSOCUT00000010968 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 45 | 67 | ENSOCUT00000010968 |
| 12 | star | intron | 60 | 88 | ENSOCUT00000060283 |

And I want to extract only rows 1, 2, 3, 5 to have a final result looking like this:

| seqid | source | Type | start | end | attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | star | CDS | 15 | 70 | ENSOCUT00000011013 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 21 | 80 | ENSOCUT00000064484 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 23 | 86 | ENSOCUT00000013302 |
| 12 | star | CDS | 45 | 67 | ENSOCUT00000010968 |

Comment: Do you need `df1[df1$Type == 'CDS',]` here?

Answer (score 4):

```
df1[c(1,2,3,5),]
```

In general to select numbered rows/columns in the brackets of a data.frame df:

```
df[rows_selected_go_here, columns_selected_go_here]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you only want those entries from `df` where `Type` (string) equals `CDS`

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- mutate(df, TOBINCL= 0)
df$TOBINCL[grepl("^CDS$", df$Type, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- 1
mynewdf <- df[(df$TOBINCL==1) , ]
```